# Estonian Digital Nomad rules for Schengen travel

Tags: schengen, digital-nomads, estonia

What are the rules of spending time and working in the Schengen zone if you have the Estonian digital nomad visa?

For example, without any visa I could spend up to 90 days in the Schengen zone without working. With the Estonian DN visa, can I spend more than 90 days in a country other than Estonia? Or can I work some of the days in a Schengen country other than Estonia?

Answer (score 1):

> With the Estonian DN visa, can I spend more than 90 days in a country other than Estonia?

Legally speaking, no.  Practically speaking, there is no systematic enforcement.

> Or can I work some of the days in a Schengen country other than Estonia?

Legally, this is determined by the law of each country.  The ones I'm familiar with would not permit it, but details will vary.

Comment: @littleadv The answer is very simple: there is no law to quote. A EU Commission report came to the conclusion many years ago that the misuse of the 90/180 day rule for residence permit holders is so small that it is simply not worth any special effort to enforce it. When someone rents and lives in a flat longer than 90 days (or pays utility bills or pays income tax), then these are signs of an overstay than can be enforced.

Comment: @MarkJohnson when someone says something is illegal - there's a law to quote. When someone says "legally speaking, no" - there's a law to quote. Last I checked the EU is a democracy and what's not explicitly forbidden by law - is not forbidden. You may want to claim that the law is not (or rarely) enforced, and again - citation needed. My point is that phoog is repeatedly downvoting my answers because in his opinion they wouldn't withstand the scrutiny of a court review, yet he himself has no problem writing handwavy and factually incorrect answers with no sources whatsoever.

Comment: @littleadv this answer is handwavy, sure, but it's not factually incorrect.  It agrees with your source.

Comment: @littleadv You yourself, in your answer, use the '90 days within any 180 days' term without citing the relevant article in the Schengen Border Code. Kindly practice what you preach before demanding the same from others. I can find no fault in his second statement. A D-Visa is a **National Visa** based on the national law of the country that issue it in the **Uniform format for visas** which is also used for Irish and UK visas (and not, as you claimed, a 'standard Schengen visa'). So your answer is also not 100% correct.

Comment: @MarkJohnson I did cite the Estonian government website, which IMHO is authoritative enough. More to the point - I provided *a reference* to my claim. i expect the person that downvotes me claiming I'm wrong to make at least the same amount of effort

Comment: @littleadv I haven't downvoted your answer to this question, nor has anyone else, nor have I criticized it in any way, least of all to say that it is incorrect.  If you want to discuss your answers to other questions, or demand sources for my assertions about them, let's do it somewhere else.

Comment: @phoog I explained why I downvoted this answer. It has nothing to do with my answers anywhere else, but I do wish to apply the standard that you demand of me to you as well. Your standard was that my answers have to withstand the scrutiny of being absolutely correct at the deepest level of the most irrelevant details. Your answer doesn't withstand that standard.

Comment: Guys. Chill. Remember we're all on the same side here, with the same goal - to help others.

Answer (score 0):

The digital nomad visa is essentially an Estonian variation of a standard Schengen visa. There are two types - C (short term) and D (long term). The digital nomad part is a work authorization from Estonian government and doesn't affect any other government in the EU. The visa itself is a standard Schengen visa and gives you no right to work anywhere in the EU.

The D visa allows staying in Estonia for up to a year, and up to 90 days within any 180 days in any other Schengen country ([source](https://vm.ee/en/long-stay-d-visa)):

> D-visa may be issued for the period of stay of up to 365 days within twelve consecutive months and it allows to stay in other Schengen Member States up to 90 days within the period of 180 days.